# ConstraintLayout width 0

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I use ConstraintLayout in xml:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/LabelTv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:text="test"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout/>
```

I know if use 0dp for android:layout_width, mean full width.
I need to play the animation from 100dp to 0dp, but when playing this, last value 0 error and textView width full.

```
ValueAnimator va = ValueAnimator.ofInt(100 ,0);
va.setDuration(3000);
va.addUpdateListener(valueAnimator -> {
      leftLabelTv.getLayoutParams().width = (int) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
      leftLabelTv.requestLayout();
});
va.start();
```

any body can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with [ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams. matchConstraintMaxWidth](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams#matchconstraintmaxheight):

```
ValueAnimator va = ValueAnimator.ofInt(100 ,0);
va.setDuration(3000);
va.addUpdateListener(valueAnimator -> {
      ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) leftLabelTv.getLayoutParams()
      params.matchConstraintMaxWidth = (int) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
      leftLabelTv.requestLayout();
});
va.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use 1 intead of 0?
from 100 to 1?